# WebSocket operation timed out with javascript

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm standing in front of an big problem. I want to connect to a cam, i can send LIMA protocols.
To Try if the cam can do all operations I've used IP Tools, that works.
Now I'm trying to connect via javascript

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.137.9:32001', ['soap', 'xmpp']);
console.log('Ready? ' + connection.readyState);
```

After 30 seconds I'll get the error "websocket error network error 12002 the operation timed out". the ReadyState is 0 at the beginning and then 3.

What I'm doing wrong? why it is not working?

Comment: "...timed out" , give us details about error .

Comment: the console log pushes after 30 seconds :
"websocket error network error 12002 the operation timed out"

Comment: I'm seeing this exact error, using SignalR.